# period of 2 years in Arima

Tags: python, python-3.x, time-series, arima

How can i set a period of 2 years for values of m in auto_arima function here -

```
import pmdarima

stepwise_model = auto_arima(data.tractors_sold, start_p=1, start_q=1,
                           max_p=3, max_q=3, m=12,
                           start_P=0, seasonal=True,
                           d=1, D=1, trace=True,
                           error_action='ignore',  
                           suppress_warnings=True, 
                           stepwise=True)
print(stepwise_model.aic())
```

Answer (score 0):

As per pmdarima github source:
`m` refers to the number of periods in each season.

Internally it is calling statsmodel sarimax model. there it become `s` and as per docs:

```
`s` is an integer giving the periodicity (number of periods in season), often it
is 4 for quarterly data or 12 for monthly data. Default is no seasonal effect.
So all above points is for one year of periodicity. So if you have daily data
and you want to set periodicity of 2 years then you have to set m = 365 * 2,
which wont work as it is used in power. so for that you have to make data monthly
or quarterly or yearly and then set m = 24(for monthly data, i.e. 24 points will
make period.), m = 8 for quarterly data and m = 2 for yearly data.
```

```
   The SARIMA model is specified :math:`(p, d, q) \times (P, D, Q)_s`.
    .. math::
        \phi_p (L) \tilde \phi_P (L^s) \Delta^d \Delta_s^D y_t = A(t) +
            \theta_q (L) \tilde \theta_Q (L^s) \zeta_t
```

check below link for more details:

https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/master/statsmodels/tsa/statespace/sarimax.py

Comment: no, it doesn't. m must be a positive integer. How to set it for 2 years?

Comment: tell me one thing, how your data is indexed with time. is it daily data or monthly or yearly?

Comment: it's on daily basis

Comment: so you have daily data, are you sure periodicity is with 2 years? if you want to set period with 2 years, first make it monthly or quarterly data then set m to 24(monthly) i.e. 24 points(2 years) will make a period, 8 for quarterly data.